# Blazor-MAUI .c ssfiles not found?

Tags: ios, blazor, maui, maui-blazor

I have a Blazor-MAUI app that run in windows and android platform. I'm trying to launch in old ipad, but, when i change debug device to ipad and compile. I have a lot of error: all the custom components and pages css files are unfound.

Maybe i forget to do something? I try to found some config file where i can validate de *.css file path with not success.

Comment: I have the same issues when i run it in android. Windows work fine, android all css files are empty...In Blazor Server you configure the PhysicalFileProvider with app.UseStaticFiles() but in Maui Blazor there is no such method.

Comment: I have finally solved it by putting all the css together in a single file in the css folder inside wwwroot, but it is a pity to lose the hierarchy of components for ios .

Comment: sorry for not posting this as an answer, but i got banned despite not having any previous answers posted